# Scraping an infinite scroll page stops without scrolling

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am currently working with PhantomJS and CasperJS to scrape for links in a website. The site uses javascript to dynamically load results. The below snippet however is not getting me all the results the page contains. What I need is to scroll down to the bottom of the page, see if the spinner shows up (meaning there’s more content still to come), wait until the new content had loaded and then keep scrolling until no more new content was shown. Then store the links with class name `.title` in an array. Link to the [webpage](http://example.com/) for scraping.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var urls = [];
function tryAndScroll(casper) {
  casper.waitFor(function() {
    this.page.scrollPosition = { top: this.page.scrollPosition["top"] + 4000, left: 0 };
    return true;
  }, function() {
    var info = this.getElementInfo('.badge-post-grid-load-more');
    if (info["visible"] == true) {
      this.waitWhileVisible('.badge-post-grid-load-more', function () {
        this.emit('results.loaded');
      }, function () {
        this.echo('next results not loaded');
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, function() {
    this.echo("Scrolling failed. Sorry.").exit();
  }, 500);
}

casper.on('results.loaded', function () {
  tryAndScroll(this);
});

casper.start('http://example.com/', function() {
    this.waitUntilVisible('.title', function() {
        tryAndScroll(this);
      });
});

casper.then(function() {
  casper.each(this.getElementsInfo('.title'), function(casper, element, j) {
    var url = element["attributes"]["href"];
    urls.push(url);
  });
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.echo(urls.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(urls.join('\n')).exit();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've looked at the page. Your misconception is probably that you think the `.badge-post-grid-load-more` element vanishes as soon as the next elements are loaded. This is not the case. It doesn't change at all. You have to find another way to test whether new elements were put into the DOM.

You could for example retrieve the current number of elements and use `waitFor` to detect when the number changes.

```
function getNumberOfItems(casper) {
    return casper.getElementsInfo(".listview .badge-grid-item").length;
}

function tryAndScroll(casper) {
  casper.page.scrollPosition = { top: casper.page.scrollPosition["top"] + 4000, left: 0 };
  var info = casper.getElementInfo('.badge-post-grid-load-more');
  if (info.visible) {
    var curItems = getNumberOfItems(casper);
    casper.waitFor(function check(){
      return curItems != getNumberOfItems(casper);
    }, function then(){
      tryAndScroll(this);
    }, function onTimeout(){
      this.echo("Timout reached");
    }, 20000);
  } else {
    casper.echo("no more items");
  }
}
```

I've also streamlined `tryAndScroll` a little. There were completely unnecessary functions: the first `casper.waitFor` wasn't waiting at all and because of that the `onTimeout` callback could never be invoked.

Comment: +1 Great, you are right about the misconception i had. Now when I run there is error: `Wait timeout of 10000ms expired, exiting.`. Could you post the whole code block? I must be putting it together wrong

Comment: Yes, the problem was that without passing an onTimeout callback the timeout error is thrown and the script stops prematurely. I added the callback and increased the timeout. Keep in mind that now there are 600 links on the page and a newly created link to open the second page which can be scrolled to load more items.

Comment: perfect! I understand now the issue wit the onTimeout callback

Comment: You are right it scrapes all 600 results, could it be possible just to scrape max 100 results?

Comment: Sure, the `curItems` variable is right there. You can use another if block to check if it is larger than 100 and only if it is smaller do the `casper.waitFor` after that.

Comment: I am now getting a resource failed. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112283/loading-resource-failed-casperjs