# scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, cheerio

I saw this question : [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

I am trying to do the same with a little more complexity.
There is a website which loads the dynamic content exactly like that but after a certain scroll, a stack comes which when clicked loads the dynamic content and I have to keep on clicking to get the result.

Here, is the link: http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=clp_mobiles_CategoryLinksModule_0-2_catergorylinks_11_ViewAll

Can someone help me how to achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: You can try to port the suggestions in these two questions to phantomjs-node or a similar bridge between PhantomJS and node.js: [How to scroll down with Phantomjs to load dynamic content](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16561582/1816580) and [Scraping an infinite scroll page stops without scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29017726/1816580)

Comment: You need to check the Ajx that they are hitting, and the json response. If you are lucky, u will get everything u need in the response json itself.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks a lot, that indeed is a lot of help. Can it be done without phantom ie just using cheerio?

Comment: No idea. I haven't used cheerio, but I don't think that it has a complete DOM+JavaScript runtime. I might be wrong.